# Dynamic hash array in Multipart call in Android with retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit, okhttp, multipart

A long time since my last question here!

Straight to the point: need to send a dynamic dictionary array in `Android` using `Retrofit`, with the following (simple enough) structure:

```
{
  “fields”: [
  {
    “first: “a”,
    “last”: “b”
  },
  {
    “first: “a”,
    “last”: “b”
  },
  …
  ]
}
```

If this was a `@FormUrlEncoded` annotated call it would be fine, problem is I need to send an image as well, so it's a `@Multipart` one.

I've successfully sent string params in `@Multipart` calls with `RequestBody`, but all my attempts have failed.

According to the [code](https://github.com/square/retrofit/pull/1326/commits/cada3aeb107c8d21dce02a6ab281220e857cf1e3), retrofit added support for iterable params and this is the way to do it

```
@Multipart
@POST("/foo/bar/")
Call<ResponseBody> method(@Part("ping") List<String> ping);
```

But I've done

```
@Multipart
@POST("/etc")
Call<Object> sendStuff(@Part("fields") List<Map<String, String>> fields);

List<Map<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < fields.size(); i++) {
  ...
  HashMap<String, String> h = new HashMap<>();
  h.put("first", first);
  h.put("last", last);
  list.add(h);
}
getService(context).sendStuff(list);
```

And it doesn't work. With a 2 item list, I only get the last one and directly as a hash, not inside an array

```
{"fields"=>"{\"first\":\"a\",\"last\":\"b\"}"}
```

Tried sending a `Map<String, RequestBody>` list, creating each value with `RequestBody.create(param, MediaType.parse("text/plain"))` but got an empty hash on the server `{"intervals"=>"{}"}`.

Tried a number of different things, like sending a `RequestBody` directly via `MultipartBody.Builder` as seen somewhere but no luck. I also got "close" doing

```
Call<Object> sendStuff(@PartMap Map<String, RequestBody> params);
    
LinkedHashMap<String, RequestBody> mp = new LinkedHashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < fields(); i++) {
  ...
  mp.put("fields[" + i + "][first]", RequestBody.create(first, MediaType.parse("text/plain")));
  mp.put("fields[" + i + "][last]", RequestBody.create(last, MediaType.parse("text/plain")));
}
Call<?> call = getService(context).sendStuff(mp);
```

which results in a hash with numbered indexes.

```
{"fields"=>{"0"=>{"first"=>"12:42", "last"=>"13:03"}, "1"=>{"first"=>"13:30", "last"=>"13:42"}}}
```

which is still far. Need an array. In `iOS`, using `Alamofire`, I'm using the following code, which creates the expected array instead of a dictionary. Pretty straightforward stuff

```
rootValue.forEach { element in
  for key in element.keys {
    if let value = element[key] as? String, let data = value.data(using: .utf8) {
      multipartFormData.append(data, withName: "\(rootKey)[][\(key)]")
    }
  }
}
```

Tried a number of variations, including the "official" one and none work. I guess I'm missing something, doesn't seem like it should be hard to do but I ran out of ideas.